# How to define the signature of a function that returns an object while passing props using interfaces?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-props, method-signature

I am working with *(.ts)* and I have defined a component where my major stylings are. I am importing an another component inside of it where I want to pass these styles as props.

The styles I made into the parent component is into the form of the function which takes 1 parameter and switch that parameter as per the different cases i gave inside of it.

Here's my parent component

```
export default function ParentComponent () {
const myStyles = (type : string) => {
switch (type) {
case 'typeA' : return {
borderRadius : '20px',
border : '1px solid #000',
color : 'yellow'
};
case 'typeB' : {
borderRadius : '10px',
border : '1px solid #fff',
color : 'pink' }}};

return (
<IconButton 
sx = {myStyles('typeA')}
>
<OtherComponent 
type = {myStyles('typeB')}
/> // this is my other component which I defined seperately and using this function as props over there
)}
```

// my other component

```
imports ...

interface Props {
myStyles : (type : string) => void;
}

export default function OtherComponent (props : Props) {
return (
<IconButton 
 sx = {props.myStyle('typeB')}
/>
)}
```

// it is throwing me an error

```
Type '{ borderRadius: string; border: string; color: string; }' provides no match for the signature '(type: string): void'.
```

// what type of signature should I provide for a function which returns styles wrapped inside an object, just like i mentioned above into 'myStyles()'..

the .ts is giving me the warning as `myStyle : (type : string) => void;` is not a valid signature of this type of function.

I tried changing signature to

```
myStyle : (type: string) => {
borderRadius : string;
border : string;
color : string
}; inside of interface Props but it didn't work as well.

All suggestions are welcome and would be highly appritiated.
```

Comment: Could you please fix the code indentation to make your question more readable?

Comment: We could really use a well-formatted self-contained [mre] suitable for demonstrating your issue when pasted into a standalone IDE.  Right now that code is just all errors, most of which are not related to your question. I tried fixing what I assume are typos but it's starting to take more effort than I'm willing to expend on getting to the *start* of a question.  If you decide to [edit] the code in this question to be usable in an IDE and want me to take another look, please mention @jcalz in a comment to notify me. Good luck!